# Finding strings that are each separated by the same string

Tags: python, regex, string

I am using python regular expressions.
My inputs are strings like these:

```
[In 1]: Names = "John r Spencer Farrow r David K r Gillian"
[In 2]: Names = "Andrew r Eli Ltd"
```

i.e. There are any number of parties (like "John", or "Spencer Farrow") that are all separated by " r ".

I want my output to be a list of strings, the strings being the parties. Like this

```
[Out 1]: ["John", "Spencer Farrow", "David K", "Gillian"]
[Out 2]: ["Andrew", "Eli Ltd"]
```

The code I have tried is variations of this

```
re.findall(r'[^(\sr\s)\w\s]+', Names)
```

i.e. I try to exclude the specific string \sr\s (or " r ") from the character set including spaces and word characters.

Please forgive my ignorance, I am new to regex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "John r Spencer Farrow r David K r Gillian"
>>> re.split(r'\br\b',s)
['John ', ' Spencer Farrow ', ' David K ', ' Gillian']
```

This one will get rid of arbitrary amounts of whitespace too:

```
>>> re.split(r'\b(?:\s*)r(?:\s*)\b',s)
['John', 'Spencer Farrow', 'David K', 'Gillian']
```

---

Of course, if you *know* that your seperator is always `" r "`, then you can just use `str.split`:

```
>>> s.split(' r ')
['John', 'Spencer Farrow', 'David K', 'Gillian']
```

Comment: Also, if there is whitespace around the party strings that is not part of the separator, it can be taken care of with a list comprehension or `map`: `[x.strip() for x in s.split(' r ')]`

Comment: @pcurry -- That's true -- But you can't write a simple solution that would also split on `"\tr\t"` without the use of regex.